# Need help on creating object with class

Tags: python, class, python-3.x, parameters, constructor

I need help on creating an object (a sequence of numbers) in respect to some parameters of a class. Lets say I typed in to the Python IDLE shell:

```
SuperLotto = make_lottery_set_type('SuperLotto', 6, (1,50))
   #means user can create a 'SuperLotto' with 6 numbers in range of 1 to 50
```

It would make 'SuperLotto' as a new class instance of a class called 'LotteryGameType'.

This is using the code so far:

```
class LotterySetError(Exception):
     pass               

def make_lottery_set_type(name:str, size:int, minmax:tuple):
    if minmax[0] > minmax[1]:
        raise LotterySetError('Illegal range for tuple')
    else:
        name = LotteryGameType(name, size, minmax[0], minmax[1])
    return name

class LotteryGameType:
    def __init__(self, name, set_size, min_set_number, max_set_number):
        self.name = name
        self.set_size = set_size
        self.min_set_number = min_set_number
        self.max_set_number = max_set_number
```

I want to be able to create a sequence of numbers and storing it for later use so I can use it with things like overload operators (e.g. **eq** and **ne**).

I want to be able to type into the Python IDLE shell:

```
SuperLotto([3, 4, 19, 23, 46, 27])
```

This would create an object under the parameters of SuperLotto, if not under parameters of 'SuperLotto' (say more than 6 numbers), it would raise an error. Any approach would be fine. Does anyone have any ideas on how to approach this?

Comment: Please use the [tag:python] tag to indicate that your question is about Python.

Comment: `SuperLotto` isn't a class, it's a global variable, an instance of type `LotteryGameType`, that you created by calling `make_lottery_set_type`. So, it's not going to be callable like a function, unless you add a `__call__` method to `LotteryGameType`. Which is probably not what you want. Take a step back and explain why you're trying to call it. Maybe you actually wanted it to be a class or a function, not an instance?

Comment: Let's see.. I think you're getting at the idea I'm trying to figure out. The approach would be that SuperLotto is a class so I can type in the shell:

super1 = SuperLotto([1,2,3,4,5,6])
super2 = SuperLotto([2,3,4,5,6,7])

I can compare those two:

super1 == super2

and it would return False.

Comment: So you want to write a `make_lottery_set_type` that returns a class, instead of a `LotteryGameType` instance? OK, that's doable.

Comment: Definitely! Do you know how to approach this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like what you want is for `make_lottery_set_type` to return a new `class`, presumably one that's a subclass of `LotteryGameType`, rather than returning an instance of that type.

This is actually pretty easy to do in Python. Class definitions are just normal code, that you can run anywhere, even in the middle of a function. And they have access to the local environment while they're running. And classes themselves are "first-class values", meaning you can pass them around and return them from functions. So:

```
def make_lottery_set_type(name:str, size:int, minmax:tuple):
    if minmax[0] > minmax[1]:
        raise LotterySetError('Illegal range for tuple')
    else:
        class NewLotteryGameType(LotteryGameType):
            def __init__(self, numbers):
                super().__init__(name, size, minmax[0], minmax[1])
                self.numbers = numbers
        return NewLotteryGameType
```

If you want to add other methods, that's the same as adding methods to any other class. For example:

```
def make_lottery_set_type(name:str, size:int, minmax:tuple):
    if minmax[0] > minmax[1]:
        raise LotterySetError('Illegal range for tuple')
    else:
        class NewLotteryGameType(LotteryGameType):
            def __init__(self, numbers):
                super().__init__(name, size, minmax[0], minmax[1])
                self.numbers = numbers
            def __eq__(self, rhs):
                return set(self.numbers) == set(rhs.numbers)
        return NewLotteryGameType
```

So:

```
>>> SuperLotto = make_lottery_set_type('SuperLotto', 6, (1,50))
>>> super1 = SuperLotto([1,2,3,4,5,6])
>>> super2 = SuperLotto([6,5,4,3,2,1])
>>> super3 = SuperLotto([7,8,9,10,11,12])
>>> super1 == super2
True
>>> super1 == super3
False
```

(Obviously you can define `__eq__` however you want, if set-equality isn't the right rule for your use.)

---

If you try to inspect the values you're generating, they don't look quite as pretty as you might like. For example, you'd probably rather see `SuperLotto` rather than `NewLotteryGameType` in places like this:

```
>>> super1
<__main__.NewLotteryGameType at 0x10259e490>
>>> SuperLotto.__name__
'NewLotteryGameType'
```

For that, just add `NewLotteryGameType.__name__ = name`. You might also want to copy over the docstring from the parent class, or various other things.

More generally, look at `functools.update_wrapper` (which is designed for wrapping up functions, not classes, but many of the details are the same) for inspiration, and the `inspect` module docs from your Python version for all of the attributes that classes can have.

---

In a comment, you ask:

> The only problem is that I want NewLotteryGameType to inherit the parameters such as name, set_size, min_set_number, max_set_number from LotteryGameType. So lets say I wanted to type in NewLotteryGameType.set_size in to the Python Shell. I want it to return back to me 6.

That's contradictory. If you want to inherit the instance attributes of `LotteryGameType`… well, you already do. For example:

```
>>> super1.set_size
6
```

If you want them to be accessible off the class, then they can't be instance attributes, they have to be class attributes. And just changing `set_size` to a class attribute of `LotteryGameType` and inheriting it won't work, because the whole point of a class attribute is that the same value shared by all instances of the class or any of its subclasses, and the subclasses all need different values.

But you could do something like this:

```
class LotteryGameType:
    def __init__(self, min_set_number, max_set_number):
        self.min_set_number = min_set_number
        self.max_set_number = max_set_number

def make_lottery_set_type(lottery_name:str, size:int, minmax:tuple):
    if minmax[0] > minmax[1]:
        raise LotterySetError('Illegal range for tuple')
    else:
        class NewLotteryGameType(LotteryGameType):
            name = lottery_name
            set_size = size
            def __init__(self, numbers):
                super().__init__(minmax[0], minmax[1])
                self.numbers = numbers
            def __eq__(self, rhs):
                return set(self.numbers) == set(rhs.numbers)
        return NewLotteryGameType
```

(Notice that I had to rename the first `make_` parameter to `lottery_name` so it was different from the class attribute `name`, because of the way scopes work.) Now, `name` and `set_size` are not instance attributes, nor are they class attributes of `LotteryGameType`—but they're class attributes of each `NewLotteryGameType`. So:

```
>>> SuperLotto = make_lottery_set_type('SuperLotto', 6, (1,50))
>>> SuperDuperLotto = make_lottery_set_type('SuperDuperLotto', 8, (1,100))
>>> SuperLotto.set_size
6
>>> SuperDuperLotto.set_size
8
```

What if you create instances of those types? Well, Python looks for attributes in the instance, then in the most-derived class, and then the base classes. So as long as you don't create instance attributes with the same name (notice that I removed the extra params, and the code that set instance attributes, from the `LotteryGameType.__init__` method), it does just what you'd want:

```
>>> super1 = SuperLotto([1,2,3,4,5,6])
>>> super1.set_size
6
>>> duper1 = SuperDuperLotto([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8])
>>> duper1.set_size
8
```

Of course this means that `LotteryGameType` is no longer a usable type on its own; only its subclasses are usable. But that's probably what you wanted anyway, right? You could even consider making it explicitly an [abstract base class](http://docs.python.org/3.3/library/abc.html) to make sure nobody accidentally tries to use a direct `LotteryGameType` instance.

If you're feeling brave, you might want to read up on metaclasses and see how you could adapt this whole design into use a `LotteryGameMetaclass`, so each new class is an instance of that metaclass instead of a subclass of the (abstract) base class. The source for the new [`enum`](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/tip/Lib/enum.py) module in 3.4, or the near-equivalent external [`flufl.enum`](https://code.launchpad.net/flufl.enum) package, might make good sample code. Then you can play with both and see how similar and how different they are.

Comment: Woah, thank you very much! We can add overload operators under NewLotteryGameType right? 

EDIT: I just added __repr__ under it. And it works. This goes for __ne__ and __eq__ as well? :)

Comment: @user2559679: I already added `__eq__` under it. So of course you can add `__ne__` as well.

Comment: Hmm, so I'm almost finished with my program. The only problem is that I want `NewLotteryGameType` to inherit the parameters such as `name, set_size, min_set_number, max_set_number` from `LotteryGameType`.

So lets say I wanted to type in `NewLotteryGameType.set_size` in to the Python Shell.

I want it to return back to me `6`. Any ideas on how to do that?

Comment: What you're asking for is contradictory. In `LotteryGameType`, the `set_size` is an instance attribute, not a class attribute. And it gets inherited exactly as you'd want: `super1.set_size` will return 6. But that means you can't access it off a class, only off an instance of the class. If you want to make it a class attribute instead, you can… but then it's not inherited from `LotteryGameType`, it's defined by each new subclass. So… which one do you want?